# How to know the problem when i make this Full Backup Scenario?

Tags: sql-server, backup

i'm working new on database administrator and i have some questions
if i want to make SQL full backup database every Saturday at 6:00 AM
and for some reasons the device was shutdown
the questions are :
whats the issues for my backup ? is it rollback ?
how can i know that was happened , when its not the time of work ?
what the a good plan to be sure to take the backup every week with out problems

Comment: If SQL Server is down when backup schedule is about to run backup job it wont be able to start backup. If backup is running and then sql server stops backup would fail and you need to start it again when sql server comes online

Answer (score 1):

If the database is down when the backup is supposed to start the backup can not run. If the database goes offline while the backup is running the backup will simply stop. It'll need to be restarted after the database comes back online.

There won't be anything logged that there was a backup running when the database went offline. You'd need to look at the job history of the backup job to see if it was running when the database went offline.

There's no way to guarantee that the backups run without issue.